# How to remove top section in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm currently using vscode 1.36 and there is a top section that I want to hide, but I can't find any setting to perform this.

[Click here for the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pfg7G.png)

**the X on the right won't fix the problem**

I've already searched on Google but found nothing interesting except writing custom css using an extension. I don't like this approach.

Note that I've disabled tabs using this setting:

```
 "workbench.editor.showTabs": false
```

Comment: Can you not just press the x?

Comment: the X is used to close the current opened file (alternative to ctrl+w)